# Scala - Implicit conversion to implicit argument

Tags: scala

I have a class `A` which also defines an implicit conversion to `B`.

```
case class A(number:Int) 
case class B(number:Int, tag:String)
implicit def  AtoB(a:A) = B(a.number,"Hello World")
```

I also have a function that retrieves `A` and would like to invoke a function that takes as argument implicit `B`:

```
def hello()(implicit b:B)= {....}
def execute = {
    implicit val a:A  = ....
    hello()  //doesnt compile missing implicit parameter b
}
```

How can I get this code to work without explicitly defining `B`? i.e

```
val b:B = a
```

Comment: The only thing you can do is `hello()(a)` or create another function. scala by design doesn't allow 'chains' of implicits.

Comment: That is not completely correct. If you call a method with an implicit parameter of the same type as an implicit parameter given to the method you're currently in, it will be passed through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a function like this:

```
implicit def implicitBfromA(implicit a: A): B = a
```

And either have it in scope when you call `hello`, or put it into the companion object of `B`.

This function is not an implicit conversion. It states, that there is an implicit value of type `B` available, if there is already an implicit value of type `A` available in the scope.

Note that it for it to work, it should either be defined *after* `AtoB` in the file, or `AtoB` should have an explicitly specified return type: `implicit def AtoB(a:A): B = B(a.number, "Hello World")`, or you should explicitly call `AtoB` in its body: `implicit def implicitBfromA(implicit a: A): B = AtoB(a)`

A full working example:

```
case class A(number: Int)

case class B(number: Int, tag: String)
object B {
  implicit def implicitB(implicit a: A): B = a
}

implicit def AtoB(a:A): B = B(a.number, "Hello World")

def hello()(implicit b: B) = b.number.toString + b.tag

def execute = {
  implicit val a: A = A(10)
  hello()
}
```